# ARM-NEON for video format conversion

Tags: arm, simd, neon

I am trying to accelerate some video frame conversion using the NEON of an ARM-based embedded system (Gumstix Overo). Source is monochrome (Y12 or Y10) and destination is RGB565, RGB888 or RGB32. Are there some specific techniques/tricks for one to learn and make use of the ARM NEON to accelerate such conversion and benchmark it against the standard C implementation.

Comment: You'll need to learn to write ARM NEON SIMD code, either using asm or C/C++ intrinsics. Search for the `[neon]` tag here on SO as there are plenty of examples.

Comment: SIMD programming with NEON is very similar to programming with SSE on x86. Properly written code should get you 3-5X speed improvement in your specific function. ARM provides some example code and you can probably find some good examples here on StackOverflow.

Comment: You can also check [libyuv](http://code.google.com/p/libyuv/) to see if they do what you want already.

Answer (score 0):

You better learn a little about Neon architecture and its compiler support. You can start by reading [this](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CG4QFjAA&url=http://www.arm.com/files/pdf/neon_support_in_the_arm_compiler.pdf&ei=DaEQUM-KIcKdiQKd6YGIAQ&usg=AFQjCNHa-3ShhDoemknhutIwdN-rO2s2vw&sig2=_MCsEBd-nWRdPn0WJ9lhlg). It is quite useful for new users.